# Do I need to (or should I) wrap all my Vue components in a wrapper component?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to put together Webpack 4.5 and Vue components. **The build is fine and I see on the screen the expected two components (details below).**

Creating this basic SPA was a very iterative process, with information gathered from various sources (not always consistent). I finally end up with:

- an HTML file which has one Vue component, a wrapper for the whole SPA
- the Vue component above, which itself brings in the actual useful components

**Is there a way to skip the wrapper component so that I can directly edit the HTML file** (and link a CSS style file)? I would then define a CSS grid and place the components within.

**Or is there an advantage to keep it this way I do not foresee?**

The current project files:

#### the HTML file opened in the browser

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <infoscreen id="infoscreen"></infoscreen>
</body>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>

</html>
```

#### the webpack config file

```
'use strict'
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')


module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: [
        './src/entry.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
            from: 'src/infoscreen.html',
            to: 'infoscreen.html'
        }])
    ]
}
```

#### the `entry.js` file

```
import infoscreen from "./infoscreen.vue"
import Vue from "vue/dist/vue.js"
Vue.component("infoscreen", infoscreen)

new Vue({ el: "infoscreen" })
```

#### the Vue wrapper component (`infoscreen.vue`)

This is the file I would like to get rid of and use `<temperature-outside></temperature-outside>` directly in the HTML file above

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <temperature-outside></temperature-outside>
        <temperature-outside></temperature-outside>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import temperatureOutside from './temperatureOutside.vue'

    export default {
        name: 'infoscreen',
        components: {
            'temperature-outside': temperatureOutside
        }
    }
</script>
```

#### the Vue component (`temperatureOutside.vue`)

```
<template>
<div>
  hello {{yo}}
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'temperatureOutside',
  data: function () {
    return {
      yo: "world"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Vue components are recognized within the context of a Vue instance. It turns out you will need a mounting point in your html which the wrapping or parent Vue component will mount all child components registered.

[Registering Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html)

Comment: OK, so in other words I have to go with the code I provided in my question?

Comment: @Woj  yes, please. :)